# Database design advice for mobile phones with variations

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I am building a mini site that will allow people to search for gadgets (phones, tablets etc..) by name and model number, the issue I have is how best to setup the database when you take into account the name conventions of some phones.

For instance, the Samsung Galaxy S mobile phone has numerous variations as well as the model number which is GT-I9000.
e.g Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000 (Variations below)

- Samsung Captivate
- Samsung Vibrant
- Samsung Fascinate
- Samsung Epic 4G
- Samsung Mesmerize

Would anybody be able to offer some advice on the best way for me to design these tables - essentially this project will have quite a large database eventually so I am trying to plan it accordingly.

I am hoping to be able to setup the database to enable the user to search for 'Captivate' or 'Vibrant' and that would show them the Galaxy S GT-I9000 as this is the 'main' name for the device.

I have currently have the following database tables

```
brands - id, brand (eg 2, Samsung)
devices - id, brand_id, device_type_id, name (eg 1, 2, 3, Galaxy S)
device_types - id, type (eg 3, phone)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is required to understand what I am trying to achieve, i'll be using MySQL for the database.

Comment: While it's realtively easy to come up with various schemas which describe your data, in determining which is the best one, we'd really need to know how you expect users to interact with the data. A very flexible schema would make it easy to search for a specific phone - but more difficult to identify cross-caegoraizations of phones e.g. to search for phones which support GPS.

Comment: The actual search will only be limited to the name & model number. For instance a user would search for "Galaxy S" or "i9000" or "Vibrant". I will be doing some additional mapping later for attributes such as GPS but there will be no need for users to know details such as GPS as it will be purely be used for users to "find" their phone regardless if it is using a variant name.

Comment: I've decided to add another table called 'device_variants' this will have contain the variants of the Galaxy S such as 'Vibrant', 'Captivate' etc... Would you say this is the best way to do this? I will do a schema shortly.

Comment: Maybe a variable length hierarchy would be more appropriate.

Comment: @symcbean could you explain further what you mean by a 'variable length hierarchy' i'd be interesting to hearing your thoughts - thanks again

Comment: A tree (just about any type of tree - self join, adjacency model, RTBT...)

Comment: @Zabs - did you manually input the phones/models? Looking for an API/database to use that has carrier specific models.

Comment: @meder i had a system which inputted the data from xml/csv files coming from publicly available files from a number of suppliers.
Although it did need manual inputting & corrections due to suppliers not always matching to our standards so it was very tedious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Litigation support systems run into this problem all the time with respect to people. The usual approach is to build a table of aliases.  The simplest structure is a table of just two columns.

```
create table device_aliases (
  device_id integer not null,
  device_alias varchar(20) not null,
  primary key (device_id, device_alias),
  foreign key (device_id) references devices (id)
);
```

Comment: This is the method I used in the end